# Ruby on Rails video_tag Errors in Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, video, html5-video

I have an mp4 file:

```
/assets/videos/myfile.mp4
```

I have this line of code in my dev.rb:

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/videos"
```

My view:

```
<td><%= video_tag "myfile.mp4", :controls => true, :autobuffer => true %> <br>
        <%= link_to 'enter' %>
</td>
```

I get output on the page, but it's just a **black box** with the controls at the bottom. When I press play nothing happens, but I fetched it properly according to the server logs:

```
Started GET "/assets/myfile.mp4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-22 17:25:41 -0400
```

Other posts are for 'no route matches GET', mine sees the file, but cannot load it properly.

**Update:** Wow it works in some old version of Safari but not in Chrome 35.0.1916.153.

**What Must I Do To Get This Working In Chrome?**

Comment: What browser are you trying with and on which OS?

Comment: Chrome -35.0.1916.153 10.8.5

Comment: I've had problems with Chrome's handling of the video tag, not even mentioning firefox... This isn't an issue on the server side but rather on the client side. Try viewing it with Safari (on OS X I got the best compatibility with Safari out of all browsers with HTML5's video tag).